# Thread safety Hector queries

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, hector

I'm using [Hector](http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/index.html) to read from [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) DB.

I would like to know if Hector's queries objects are thread safe, specifically I would like to know if the following are thread safe:

- SliceQuery
- StringSerializer.get()

I create my query using this code:

```
StringSerializer stringSerializer = StringSerializer.get();
query = HFactory.createSliceQuery(connectionEvent.getKeyspace(), stringSerializer, stringSerializer, stringSerializer);
```

Can I take this code to the class level, assuming it is thread safe and then use it in the class methods (which should be thread safe for a multi-threaded environment)?

I have found no documentation that relates to this subject. In case those objects are not thread safe I will make sure their initialization takes place inside the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StringSerializer is thread safe hence can be put in class level,
the query on the other hand isn't hence needs to be created again during each request.